# Accumulation points and Boundary points of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequenc. Denote $A$ as the set of accumulation points of the sequence. Now define $B = \{ x_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Is it true in general that:

$$A = \partial B$$

I know Bolzano-Weierstrass tells us that if the sequence is bounded, then A is non-empty and compact, and then I believe I have a proof for this (or perhaps this is false as well?)

However, is it true in general?

Seems like most would agree on this inclusion: $A \subset \partial B$. My proof for the other direction is pretty simple:

Let $x \in \partial B$, thus $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap B$ so $\forall \epsilon > 0$,  $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ contains some point of B. But since we can just take epsilon to be the distance from x to that point, then there exists some other point in this epsilon neighborhood which is in $B$, thus $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ contains infinitely many points of B (not great at formalizing this...)

Then we have that x is an accumulation point (since x is acc. point iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 $, $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence), so $\partial B \subset A$. Am I missing something? Any help/info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe misunderstanding, but I believe $$A = \partial B$$ is not true, rather $$A \cup B = \partial B$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_n = n$. Then $x_n$ has no accumulation points so $A = \emptyset$. $B = \{x_n\}$ has $\partial B = B$ since $\partial B = \overline{B} \setminus B^\circ$ and $\overline{B} = B$ since $B$ itself is closed and $B^\circ = \emptyset$. So we have $A = \emptyset$ and $\partial B = B \ne \emptyset$ so the statement appears to be false. As noted in the comment by Anatoliy, $A \cup B = \partial B$ seems more reasonable.